# How can I have Node re process /etc/hosts?

Tags: node.js

So for unit testing I need to redirect a domain to a new IP for a specific machine. I've setup a route in node to update the machine's hosts file.

```
exports.hosts = function hosts(req, res) {
  var domain = req.params.domain;
  var ip = req.params.ip;

  if (domain === 'localhost') {
    res.json(500, {message: 'invalid domain'});
    return;
  }

  async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
      fs.readFile('/etc/hosts', callback);
    },
    function (data, callback) {
      // Remove existing entry
      var lines = data.toString().split('\n');
      data = '';
      for (var line in lines) {
        if (!_str.endsWith(lines[line], domain) && lines[line]) {
          data += lines[line] + '\n';
        }
      }
      callback(null, data);
    },
    function (data, callback) {
      if (ip) {
        data += ip + ' ' + domain + '\n';
      }
      callback(null, data);
    },
    function (data, callback) {
      fs.writeFile('/etc/hosts', data, callback);
    }
  ],
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(500, err);
    } else {
      res.send(200);
    }
  });
};
```

The edit works fine. The issue is that I the next call to the domain from the node process still goes to the last IP address. If I restart Node it sees the new IP address in the hosts file.

How can I get Node to see the updated hosts file *without* restarting the process?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I imagine that similar to environment variables, hosts file info may be loaded and cached.  By the same token you must restart software for those new env variables to be noticed, you may need to kill the node process and restart it to get the new hosts entry.  If you install something like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), you would adjust your initial kickoff command slightly: `pm2 start app.js` instead of `node app.js`.  Then every time you update your hosts file, kill your app and pm2 will restart it. Killing your app is as easy as `process.kill()`, `process.exit()`, or throw an Error.